# Syncing Podio with SharePoint List or Excel File

Tags: sharepoint, synchronization, podio

I hava an application on Podio that report incidents by users, i need to sync these inputs "items" with a SharePoint list or Excel file automatically instead of the Export function. i tried Zapier but it was limited for free plan, i also tried Simgo application but it is also paid. is there any way to make this happened? i'm not very familiar with API but if there is something can be adapted then it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you listed solutions to make this happened: Zapier, Simgo.

Of course you can implement your own solution. You may need to review how [Podio API](https://developers.podio.com/) works, and especially [export functionality](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/export-items-4235696).